# Need a solution on connecting Teradata using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, teradata

I have a below code which will be used to connect the hadoop env with Teradata.

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:teradata://teradata-dns-sysa.fg.rbc.com",driver="com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver",dbtable="table",user="userid",password="xxxxxxxx").load()
```

Now the userid & password is different for different users. Hence looking out for a solution where credentials can be stored in a file in a secure location and the code simply refer to the data (userid & password) in the file

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use property file where you can store required user id and password in file. You can refer properties file using argument parameter **--properties-file file_name** in command  while running spark-submit command. Below is sample code for same.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("Teradata Connect") \
        .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

DB_DRIVER = sc._conf.get('spark.DB_DRIVER')

JDBC_URL = sc._conf.get('spark.JDBC_URL')

DB_USER = sc._conf.get('spark.DB_USER')

DB_PASS = sc._conf.get('spark.DB_PASS')

jdbcDF = (spark.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", DB_DRIVER)
   .option("url", JDBC_URL)
   .option("dbtable", "sql_query")
   .option("user", DB_USER)
   .option("password", DB_PASS)
   .load())

jdbcDF.show(10)
```

## Sample Properties file

> spark.DB_DRIVER com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
>
> spark.JDBC_URL jdbc:teradata://teradata-dns-sysa.fg.rbc.com
>
> spark.DB_USER userid
>
> spark.DB_PASS password

## Spark submit command

```
spark2-submit --master yarn \
              --deploy-mode cluster \
              --properties-file $CONF_FILE \
                pyspark_script.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have used the below
spark-shell --queue P_NO_SLA --master yarn --deploy-mode client --properties-file file_name.
The scala is opening and not the pyspark shell.I need this on pyspark

Comment: Code above is Pyspark only, do you need Scala one?